# Qt 6.5.0 On Android application freezes to startup

Tags: android, qt6

I use Qt 6.5.0 with android 9, at first startup, my application startup normaly with my foreground service and  when i close my application, the foreground service stay active, but when i restarted the application, she freezes to startup when foreground service is active and onCreate of my Activity is not called, I do search on Google but i nothing found.